# Jetty : Path of Extracted war

Tags: jetty

I have deployed a `.war` file inside Jetty Server.

The server has been started, but please tell me where could I see the contents of that war file??

I have read that:

> If the extract parameter is true, any packed war or zip files will
>   first be extracted to a temporary directory before being deployed.

Please tell me where can I set the extract parameter is true and what will be the temporary folder path??

This is my `jetty-webapps.xml` file

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
          <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
            <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider">
                <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps</Set>
                <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
                <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
                <Set name="contextXmlDir"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/contexts</Set>
        <Set name="extractWars">true</Set>
              </New>
            </Arg>
          </Call>
    </Ref>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the war files which you deploy are extracted in `Jetty_Home/work` for deployment. But if you want that war files should be extracted in temp folder before deployed to work folder, then you can set the `extractWars` parameter as true in `jetty-webapps.xml` file. The `jetty-webapps.xml` file is located in `Jetty_HOME/etc/` folder.

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
          <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
            <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider">
                <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps</Set>
                <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
                <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
                <Set name="contextXmlDir"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/contexts</Set>
        <Set name="extractWars">true</Set>
              </New>
            </Arg>
          </Call>
    </Ref>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but i could not able to find thw work folder , i am using jetty8

Comment: do you have etc folder inside your jetty_home? are you using linux? and installed jetty using apt-get?

Comment: check for jetty-webapp.xml, it should has extractWar field set to true. Also, which version of jetty you are running?

Comment: I am using Jetty8 and this is my jetty-webapp.xml file ( i have modified my question to add jetty-webapps.xml file inside etc folder ) as you can see already there is that extractWars set to true .

Comment: Look at the  "extractWars" parameter, it is already set to true, now when you deploy any war, it will be first extracted in temp folder before deploying. the location of temp folder is /tmp (Linux temp folder)

Comment: is your problem solved? are you able to find the extracted war inside /tmp? if your problem is solved then kindly upvote my answer and accept it :)

Comment: Just wanted to know where this will be extracted incase if i am using windows environment .

Comment: if You are using windows, then jetty_home folder will a temp folder. Also if you download a zip version of jetty and run it on linux, you will find a temp folder inside jetty_home.

Answer (score 7):

Check the log file. It should have a like like this

> 2012-11-06 17:41:54.334:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/usr/oc/jcast8083/webapps/spdy.war!/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8083-spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp

In this case, the content of the war file is in

> /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8083-spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Link](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg01998.html):

You have few choices.

1) Specify your own java.io.tmpdir java system property location for jetty to use.

```
$ java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/my/new/temp/ -jar start.jar
```

2) Create a "work" directory under the `${jetty.home}` path (whereever that is).
    That will cause Jetty to use that work directory instead of whatever the `java.io.tmpdir` property is set to.

3) Specify the tempDir attribute on the WebAppProvider deployments.

Only valid for war file deployment scenarios, NOT valid for context based deployment.

If you have `etc/jetty-webapps.xml` in your `start.ini` you have war file deployments enabled.

Edit the `${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-webapps.xml` file and add 1 more attribute on the WebAppProvider.
    `<Set name="tempDir">/path/to/my/preferred/temp/dir/for/all/webapps</Set>`

4) Set the tempDirectory attribute on the WebAppContext with context based deployments.
    NOT valid for war file deployment scenarios.

If you have `etc/jetty-context.xml` in your `start.ini` you have context based deployments enabled.

Edit the `${jetty.home}/contexts/myapp.xml` and add the tempDirectory attribute on the WebAppContext.
    `<Set name="tempDirectory">/path/to/my/preferred/temp/dir/for/this/context</Set>`